# Printing an html page from google cloud print and zapier

Tags: html, css, printing, zapier, google-cloud-print

I am trying to print an html document to my epson-3700 printer via zapier and google cloud print. When I print to PDF from zapier everything works out fine, the pdf is the correct size and when I print the newly created PDF it prints out just how I want it, however when I try to print from zapier directly to google cloud print on my printer it makes a huge margin around the whole page which causes the printing to be cut off.

I have tried adjusting all sorts of zapier settings and settings from my PC (manage your device) and they all dont seem to do anything. There must be something wrong with my code...?

I have been working on this for a good 10 hours and cannot seem to get it, any help is much appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@page  
{ 
    width: 4.75in;
    height: 6.5in;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;  
}

        html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 4.75in;
        height: 6.5in;
}

div.absolute1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5mm;
    left: 5mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
} 

div.absolute2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5mm;
    right: 1.5mm;
    width: 43mm;
}

div.absolute3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 63mm;
    right: 70mm;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: "Courier", courier;
    text-align: right;
}

div.absolute4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70mm;
    left: 40mm;
    font-size: 11pt;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="absolute1">
company name <br>
address <br>
address line 2<br>
</div>

....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it basically by moving the positions to the middle right and making a margin around a full letter sized paper, It doesnt work out the same when I print to PDF which is what i was trying to avoid but this will do the trick.

I dont think zapier can recognize different page sizes although it has the option to select a page size... not entirely sure what is going on here but here is my code for anyone else with the same problem:

note that my printer feeds paper from the middle rather than to one side so if your page adjust is to one side you will need to adjust accordingly
also note I am not a developer so my code is probably not the best

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@page  
{ 
    margin: 46mm 0mm 46mm 118mm;  
    padding: 0;
     width: 4.75in;
     height: 6.5in;
}

        body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}

div.returnaddress {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7mm;
    left: 7mm;
    font-size: 9pt;
} 

div.postage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3mm;
    right: 5mm;
    width: 40mm;
}

div.packagenumber {
    position: absolute;
    top: 53mm;
    right: 55mm;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-family: "Courier", courier;
    text-align: right;
}

div.recipientaddress {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60mm;
    left: 50mm;
    font-size: 11pt;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="returnaddress">
COMPANY NAME <br>
COMPANY ADDRESS <br>
ADDRESS  4Z8<br>
</div>

<div class="packagenumber"> PACKAGE NUMBER
</div>
<div class="recipientaddress"> RECIPIENT ADDRESS
</div>

<div class="postage">
<svg
....
```